# Does using an option or argument create a space at the end of the beginning of an environment?

Tags: spacing, environments

This:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newenvironment*{testenvironment}[1][]{%
    #1 some%
}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{testenvironment}
    text
\end{testenvironment}

\begin{testenvironment}[also]
    text
\end{testenvironment}

\end{document}
```

surprisingly gives this:

[image]

When one writes `\begin{testenvironment}{}`, the space is added after "some". (Like when using the option.) Yet, why is this?? It seems quite odd..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to note here is that latex is not adding space, it is just that sometimes it is ignoring space.

your environment code ends in  `some` so

```
\begin{testenvironment}text
```

produces sometext

If you add a space as in

```
\begin{testenvironment} text
```

Then had the environment had no optional argument, this would produce some text, but it produces sometext.

the reason is that latex skips over white space looking for the optional argument

```
\begin{testenvironment}[about]
```

or

```
\begin{testenvironment}    [about]
```

are both valid, so all white space is ignored after the the environment and then latex looks to see whether a `[` denoting the option is there but in either case teh space is not restored.

The case you mention with

```
\begin{testenvironment}{} test
```

does produce the space  as the scan for the optional argument ends at the `{` so the space before test produces a word space as normal. Again this is just the space that is in the document being used, the enviornment is not adding space:

```
\begin{testenvironment}{}test
```

would again produce sometest